# enzyme-to-snapshot render object as JSON

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, enzyme-to-snapshot

Why render object JSON in snapshot?

For an component

```
const MyComp =
  <Provider {...stores}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <ClassRoom.wrappedComponent {...props} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
```

I test as

```
const wrapper = mount(MyComp );
expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
```

And my snapshot is generated with object json information.

```
<Provider
  classRoomStore={ClassRoomStore {}}
  mqttStore={
    <MemoryRouter>
        <Router
          history={
            Object {
              "action": "POP",
              "block": [Function],
              "canGo": [Function],
              "createHref": [Function],
              "entries": Array [
                Object {
                  "hash": "",
                  "key": "o0ynpg",
                  "pathname": "/",
                  "search": "",
                  "state": undefined,
                },
              ],
```

With cause severals problems such as `key": "o0ynpg",` is generated for every test. So my snapshot always fail.

Comment: I think mounting should look like that:

`const wrapper = mount(<MyComp /> )`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this post wondering about turning off keys in `enzyme-to-json` in your snapshots:

```
toJson(wrapper, {
  noKey: true
});
```