# Snapshot with router not work

Tags: jestjs, snapshot, history.js, react-router-v4

**This is different from this one [enzyme-to-snapshot-render-object-as-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401936/enzyme-to-snapshot-render-object-as-json) because**

Here I want to generate snapshot **with JSON definition** of objects
The other I want generate snapshot **only for HTML** generated by component.

---

Snapshot tests always fail because the `key` property in `history` change every time.

```
// ComponentContainer.jsx
class ComponentContainer extends Component {
  render() { ... }
}
export { ComponentContainer };    
export default withRouter(ComponentContainer);
```

And the tests ..

```
// ComponentContainer.test.jsx
import { ComponentContainer } from './ComponentContainer';

const minProps = {
  history: {
    push: jest.fn(),
  },
};

const wrapped = mount(
  <Router history={minProps.history}>
    <ComponentContainer.wrappedComponent {...mergedProps} {...mergedStores} />
  </Router>,
);

expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Generate this snapshot ..

```
// ComponentContainer.test.jsx.snap
<MemoryRouter
    history={
      Object {
        "push": [Function],
      }
    }
  >
    <Router
      history={
        Object {
          "action": "POP",
          "block": [Function],
          "canGo": [Function],
          "createHref": [Function],
          "entries": Array [
            Object {
              "hash": "",
              "key": "mmldr1", // THIS IS GENERATED ON EACH TEST
              "pathname": "/",
              "search": "",
              "state": undefined,
            },
          ],
```

### Attempts

I try to use memory history ...

```
// ComponentContainer.test.jsx
import createHistory from 'history/createMemoryHistory';

const history = createHistory({
  initialEntries: [`/myapp/123`],
});

<Router history={history}>
  <ComponentContainer.wrappedComponent />
</Router>
```

But I end up the same problem.

Comment: Why not use `enzyme.find(ComponentContainer)` so you only make a snapshot of the component itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [enzyme-to-snapshot render object as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401936/enzyme-to-snapshot-render-object-as-json)

Comment: @wogsland it is not duplicated, I add more information on question explain why.

Comment: Still looks like the same key in a snapshot problem to me. Wish I had found a good solution for it myself!

Comment: @AndreasKoberle Thats my answer. Thanks. Please, add as answer so I can mark your answer.

Comment: @wogsland both fail the tests, but require different solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the retaliatory downvote on my highest ranked question all the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `enzyme.find(ComponentContainer)` to make a snapshot from the component itself not from the router.

Comment: If using shallow render then can use `wrapped.dive()` instead